# No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0', 'Variable:0']

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, regression, gradient-descent, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 2.0 for the following code for linear regression:

```py
tx = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32)
ty = tf.constant(y, dtype=tf.float32)
    
tw = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.randn(), dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
tb = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
tyhat = tx * tw  + tb
    
cost = lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tyhat-ty))
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost, var_list = [tw,tb])
```

and got an error: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0', 'Variable:0']

Any help?

Comment: should this `cost = lambda:..` be instead `cost = lambda ty:..`??

Answer (score 2):

```
tw = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.randn(), dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
tb = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)

cost =  lambda :tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tx*tw+tb-ty))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost, var_list = [tw,tb])
```

Reference to tw and tb directly in cost function rather than through yhat. It will work.